# Using Bucket DIC with constructor arguments

Tags: php, dependency-injection

I am using [Bucket DIC](https://github.com/troelskn/bucket) for injection and unit testing. 
In most cases, this type of code works fine:

```
$model_obj = $dic->get('ThatModel')
```

But I can't figure out how to use DIC in a case where the constructor has arguments:

```
class OtherModel {
    function __construct($param1,$param2) {
    }
}
```

The same DIC code doesn't work.
Are there other containers which solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By attaching a factory to your container, you can control with which arguments the controller is invoked:

```
$bucket = new bucket_Container(
  array(
    'OtherModel' => function($container) {
      return new OtherModel('first param', 'second param');
    }
  )
);

$model_obj = $bucket->get('OtherModel');
```